# Get the content of an SVG string

Tags: javascript, string, svg

Let's say that we have the following simple SVG element:

```js
const svg = `<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
    <path d="M100 100C100 44.7715 55.2285 -1.95703e-06 0 -4.37114e-06L-4.37114e-06 100L100 100Z" fill="current"/>
  </g>
</svg>`
```

The `svg` variable is a string and I want to extract all the child nodes from the svg (the `<g>` element for the specific example but can be more elements).

How can I do that without using a DOM manipulation library like JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

### Version 2

You can use `str.split()` to extract all the child elements from the `<svg>` as a string.

**Working Example:**

```js
const svg = `<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
    <path d="M100 100C100 44.7715 55.2285 -1.95703e-06 0 -4.37114e-06L-4.37114e-06 100L100 100Z" fill="current"/>
  </g>
</svg>`;

let g;
g = svg.split('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">')[1];
g = g.split('</svg>')[0];
g = g.trim();

console.log(g);
```

---

### Version 1

> I want to extract the content from the `<svg>` which is the 
> element inside it.

If I've understood correctly:

- you want to extract only the `<g>` element
- you know that the `<svg>` contains a `<g>` element
- you know that there is only one `<g>` element

you can use `str.split()` to extract the `<g>` from the `<svg>`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const svg = `<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0)">
    <path d="M100 100C100 44.7715 55.2285 -1.95703e-06 0 -4.37114e-06L-4.37114e-06 100L100 100Z" fill="current"/>
  </g>
</svg>`;

let g;
g = svg.split('<g ')[1];
g = g.split('</g>')[0];
g = '<g ' + g + '</g>'

console.log(g);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to extract all the children elements inside the SVG element. 

Thanks for the logic though because I modify the split functions to work for my goal.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, @dmraptis, I have added an improved version of the same approach to the solution above, which anyone can use to extract the entire contents of the `<svg>` as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Either use JavaScripts built in DOMParser

```
var p= new DOMParser()
var d= p.parseFromString(svg,"text/html")
var g= d.querySelector("svg g")
```

OR make your own html/xml parser from scratch by looping through each character, checking for <, if found look for some letters next for the tag, if found look for other >, get all content in between for attributes, rinse and repeat

Comment: Thanks! This can work. Maybe a custom parser to manipulate the string directly is the right solution to my problem.